# Using the YouTube API when starting an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a problem with android, I want to play a video with youtube api, I created a activity in main that references is car.class, but when I compile show error

I have main class with the last code:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,car.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

Moreover I have a car class with the last code:

```
public class car extends  Activity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

  @Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,boolean     wasRestored) {
            ytp=player;

            Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization  Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Error is:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.car
            at com.example.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
```

What can I do?

Comment: check this out. Might help - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error NoClassDefFoundError: maybe is that, you must define the activity in your Manifest file or you don't have import the correct library

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this, car.class);
startActivity(i);
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks but shows same error:FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.car
            at com.example.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:78),            in file.xml I have this code:
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />